# Link of the JSTL 1.2 Tag reference documentation

Tags: documentation, jstl, java-ee-6

In JavaEE 6 the JSTL version is 1.2. I am trying to find the link to the taglib documentation for this version. I have found the link for [1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html). However unable to find it for 1.2. I came to know that JSTL 1.2 is managed by [java.net](http://jstl.java.net/); but didn't find the documentation there. Also the [Technical Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/) for JavaEE 6 don't have any such link mentioned.

If someone have the link, please share it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for it myself today, found a .pdf at the JCP site: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr052/index2.html

Let me know if you find HTML-based doc like the one on your 1.1 link!