# Link to JSTL 1.2 official specification cannot be found anywhere

Tags: jstl, specifications

[This](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr052/index3.html) or [this](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=52) leads to [here where](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr052/index.html) I can find *official* JSTL 1.0 version specification (JSR 52 Final Release). It is very good with a lot of examples, but it is outdated (in terms of actually used nowadays JSTL 1.2) - I start reading it and see (for example) it uses this address to enable JSTL support: `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` instead of `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

So I am afraid to read it further and rely on it (I think it may be much different from version 1.2 in many other respects besides that one).

But I cannot find a working link to actually used JSTL 1.2.

Is there a working link to a revised standard (JSTL 1.2)?

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173041/link-of-the-jstl-1-2-tag-reference-documentation), but it is unanswered (and has 2000 views!).

**I am looking for  *official* documentaion which is *important* and seems to be *missing* (or not easy/obvious to find), so please consider this first as to possible "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic" - a link to official documentation cannot be something opinionated, besides I don't need a recommendation - JSTL is a part of JavaEE and is an industry standard (though may be a little old one).**

P.S. This is a useful [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) (JavaEE 8), but it also of no help.